# Unable to set many to many relationship in overwritten save method

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I am trying to create a system where I set up an issue and it automatically creates custom fields that a user will have defined stored in another model. I set my current model up with a many to many relationship to the custom field model and overwrite the save method so that each of the custom defined fields will be added with a default value.

When I use the .add method after saving my issues model, nothing seems to happen, the many to many relationships are not created. The relationships are able to be made within the Django Admin interface.

class Issue(models.Model):

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Issues"
    verbose_name_plural = "Issues"

title = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
description = models.TextField()
owner = models.ForeignKey(Organisation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
category = models.ForeignKey(IssueCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
state = models.ForeignKey(IssueStates, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
assignedTo = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
customFields = models.ManyToManyField(IssueCustomFields, blank=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    super(Issue, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    for x in IssueCustomFieldDefinitions.objects.filter(owner=self.owner):

        issueCustom = IssueCustomFields.objects.create(
            value=x.default,
            fieldDefinition = x,
            owner = self.owner,
        )

        self.customFields.add(issueCustom)
        print(self.customFields.all())
```

I expect that when the Issue model is saved, it iterates through all the custom fields that th user has set up and creates an instance of it as well as establishing relationships. The relationship is never established (the instances are created though)

Comment: So, what is IssueCustomFieldDefinitions, how is it related to Issue, and how is it being populated in the admin?

Answer (score 0):

many to many relation is not depended on save method . if you assign relation between two model with many to many you don't need to save any of those model .